# ng test angular 5 not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-unit-test

'app-footer' is not a known element:
        1. If 'app-footer' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
        2. If 'app-footer' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
Need help to fix it. I referenced many document but still not clear.

angular cli-1.7.4
Angular: 5.2.11

Thank you in Advance
XXX

Comment: Can you add some code? What is the component that yiu are testing?\

Comment: You need to read the error message. It tells you what to do. Google it if you still don't understand.

Comment: app-footer is an Angular component, right? Have you declared it in your testing module?

Answer (score 4):

When you test a component there might be child components on it's template. If you are not testing the interaction between those components you can ignore the child components in the template.
For that you have to import `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` from `@angular/core` like this.

```
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
```

Then you should add it to the test bed configurations like this.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [YourComponent],
        providers: [],
        schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
      }).compileComponents();
```

Now your test should work.

And if you want to test the child components also. You have to follow a different approach.